# Use ajax and grails to display an associated database value from a selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I am trying to create a way to select multiple values(ID's) from a database and display them by associated name while saving the ID attached to each selected value (name). I tried asking if this was possible in jquery and was told ajax could fulfill this but I know virtually no ajax. Is there a better way to approach this task or how would I need to incorporate ajax to input tags to display by name?

```
script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".claim").change(function () {
        $(".area").append("<div><input class='field' name='students_going' readonly type='text' value='" + $(this).val() + "'/><input class='field' name='students' type='hidden' value='" + $(this).val() + "'/><label class='remove fakeLink'> Remove</label></div>");
        $(this).find("option:selected").remove();
    });
    $(".area").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        var val = $(this).parent().find("input").val();         
        $(".claim").append("<option value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</option>");
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    $(".area").on("click", ".removeEdit", function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();

    });
});
</script>
```

---

```
<div class="area">
<h2>Select all students who will be visiting</h2>
<div>
<g:if test="${disabled=='false'}">
 <g:select name="selector" class="claim" value="None" from="${fullList}" optionKey="studentNumber" optionValue="${{it.firstName + ' ' + it.lastName}}" noSelection="${['null':' ']}" disabled="${disabled}"/>
   <g:if test="${fieldTripInstance?.students!= null }">
   <g:each var="i" in="${(0..<fieldTripInstance?.students?.length) }">
    <div>
     <input class='field' name='Name' readonly type='text' value='${fullList.firstName[((fieldTripInstance?.students[i]).toInteger()-1)]} ${fullList.lastName[((fieldTripInstance?.students[i]).toInteger()-1)]}'/>
     <input class='field' name='students' readonly type='hidden' value='${fieldTripInstance?.students[i]}'/>
       <label class='removeEdit fakeLink'> Remove</label>
    </div>
  </g:each>
 </g:if>
</g:if>

<g:if test="${disabled=='true'}">
<g:if test="${fieldTripInstance?.students!= null }">
 <g:each var="i" in="${(0..<fieldTripInstance?.students?.size()) }">
  <div>
   <input class='field' name='students' readonly disabled="${disabled}" type='text' value='${fieldTripInstance?.students[i]}'/>
  </div>
 </g:each>
 </g:if>
</g:if>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you want to reload the parts enclosed by you g:each tags right?

Comment: Sorry I am pretty bad a phrasing questions. :/ Right now the g:select returns a number ID of a person selected off the dropdown. When the name is selected the returned value is put into an input field to show the user the person selected and can be removed if need be. the issue is the ID's are the easiest way to call names for the select but when the value goes to the input its an ID not a name. I was hoping to find a solution to display the name but still be able to save the ID in a list for if the user needs to edit later.

Comment: You have a hidden field called student.id when user selects name the id is put into hidden field. Update of selection updates hidden field. The .id means you capture student object and grails will bind that .id field with student object. Take a look at ajaxdependancyselection plugin and how it assigns hidden field with id

Answer (score 0):

Consider the class

```
class SchoolClass {
    String className
    static  hasMany = [students: Student]

    static constraints = {
    }

    String toString(){
        className
    }
}
```

AND

```
class Student {
    String name

    static constraints = {
    }

    String toString(){
        name
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a basic view :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Index</title>
   <meta name="layout" content="main">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Class Roster</h1>

    <g:select name="class" from="${classRoster}" optionKey="id" class="ajax-loader" data-target="#ajaxContent" data-targeturl="${createLink(controller: 'schoolClass', action: 'ajaxStudents')}"/>

    <div id="ajaxContent">

    </div>

    <script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            ajaxify();
        });


        function ajaxify(){
            $(".ajax-loader").on('change', function(){
                var control = $(this);
                var targetUrl = control.data("targeturl");
                var target = control.data("target");
                console.log("Loading ajax content:"+ control + target + targetUrl);
                $(target).load(targetUrl, {controlVal : control.val()}, function(){
                    //Things done after loading
                })



            });
        }
    })(jQuery);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Checking the view you will see that I added data-target and data-targetUrl. data-target tells the function where to load the new content, and data-targetUrl will tell the function where is the content. As you can see the data-targeturl points to an action.  The little part **{controlVal : control.val()}** is where you define which parameters will be passed to the controller action.

Please do investigate the **load()** function it will help you a lot. Also, the load function I provided is a simple skeleton, you need to add error handling and some tests to ensure stability.

---

And a simple controller

```
class SchoolClassController {

    def index() {
        [classRoster: SchoolClass.list()]
    }

    def ajaxStudents(long controlVal){
           render "${controlVal}"
    }
}
```

Notice how **controlVal** has the same name than the value you passed from the jquery function. You can pass n paramaters as long as the name and type are consistent between the view and controller.

**render "${controlVal}"** can be changed to *render template: 'myTemplate', model: []*. Please do investigate the grails render function.